# How to scroll down a div container using Selenium by simulating the Page Down Key?

Tags: java, selenium, scroll

The div container is referring to the container of the menu items of a "hamburger" menu of this webpage: http://www.xm.com (note that due to being a responsive page the window size is 600px wide)

The css selector is as easy as this: `#navigation-collapse > .container:nth-of-type(1)`

The element is found ok:

```
WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(mycss));
```

However the issue rises when calling this:

```
container.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

Where there is the complaint that the element is not interactable:
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable`

Why is this happening? How could one simulate the PAGE DOWN key on this container?

*Note that the javascript way of scrolling works ok but ideally would like to avoid*

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on your question as the locator which you are showing(i.e. `#navigation-collapse > .container:nth-of-type(1)`) is at the top. So, for which element you are going down to find? Per my knowledge, it will directly go to the element if you try to interact and which is in the bottom of the page. Otherwise, you have to use JavaScriptExecutor to scroll to that element.

Anyhow give a try using '**body**' tag of the page like below and then try your Page down logic.

```
WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.tagName('body'));
container.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

please let know the update after trying this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is not the solution as if you notice I want to scroll specifically this div and not the entire page. The two can be scrolled independently. Not sure if your code above would work but either way it would scroll the entire page and not the specific div. As explained I am looking to avoid javascript executor and replicate what a user using the keyboard would do by scrolling down with the page down key

Comment: I understood your issue. Please have a look into this video link, it will use EventFiringWebdriver to do the same thing what exactly you are looking for. But it is not using JavaScriptExecutor but it uses the executeScript method to achieve the same.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZ_XIgxbyiY